# Cannot use lightgbm.dll in Pyinstaller's exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, exe, pyinstaller, lightgbm

I am trying to convert my code into an exe using pyinstaller spec.
I ran pyinstaller with the following command:

```
pyinstaller --clean --add-data lib_lightgbm.dll;\compile orca.spec
```

The exe fails with the error:

```
main__.PyInstallerImportError: Failed to load dynlib/dll 
'C:\\Users\\...\\lightgbm\\../compile\\lib_lightgbm.dll'. Most probably this 
dynlib/dll was not found when the application was frozen.
```

I have tried adding lightgbm.dll through binaries, but didnt work. I also tried manually copying it to the destination after the exe is created. That didnt work either. Most of the questions about pyinstaller and lib_lightgbm.dll failed to answer my issue. Can someone please suggest a solution? I am at my wits end at the moment.

Here is my spec file:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['mycode.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\mycode\\source code'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=['cython', 'sklearn', 'sklearn.feature_extraction','sklearn.pipeline', 'sklearn.ensemble', 'sklearn.neighbors.typedefs', 'sklearn.neighbors.quad_tree', 'sklearn.tree._utils'],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='mycode',
          debug=True,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='mycode')
```

Answer (score 0):

> When you build from a spec file, those options cannot be changed.

so either add the tuple to the `datas` section, or ommit the spec file and use all the parameters for `pyinstaller`

I'm not 100% sure this is the fix, but there should be something in your `datas` section of you spec file.  So I'd investigate that.  you can also build from a spec file using `pyinstaller <spec file here>` when you're done editing it.

https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html